# How can I make an Google Talk voice call without hands-free mode?

Tags: google-talk, microphone, speaker, hands-free

When you call someone who is online via Google Talk, it use the back speaker in loud mode. Is there a way to use GTalk for calling like a regular phone call?

Answer (score 1):

This may no longer be relevant since Voice is being replaced by Hangout, and you can only make video calls with Hangout. You could look into using a Google Voice number with a VoIP client, like [Groove IP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snrblabs.grooveip&hl=en), to make calls. [This is a great tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5807075/groove-ip-makes-free-voip-calls-from-google-voice-over-wi+fi-or-3g4g) if you need some help getting started.